# Calling another function or method from within a click handler in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, function, coffeescript, onclick

I am a CoffeeScript n00b, and I am struggling with calling another function from within my click handler.

The first alert appears, but the second does not.

```
CourseGuide =

    init: ->

      $('.js-size-unit-button').on 'click', (e) ->
        alert 'hello world - test'
        @clickHandler(e)

      clickHandler: (e) ->
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log 'hello world - test 2'
        alert 'hello world - test 2'

module.exports = CourseGuide
```

This is the error in the console:

> TypeError: this.clickHandler is not a function

Do I have a basic syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there... Change the code from this:

```
$('.js-size-unit-button').on 'click', (e) ->
```

to this:

```
$('.js-size-unit-button').on 'click', (e) =>
```

Why does this work? the "fat arrow" (`=>`) tells the CoffeeScript compiler to ensure that the value of `this` in the event handler refers to the class you've defined, instead of something else. Usually, in Javascript, if you use `this` in an event handler, `this` refers to the element on which the event was triggered.

This is described [in the section entitled "Bound Functions, Generator Functions"](http://coffeescript.org/#classes) in the Coffescript documentation.

You may also need to change the declaration of the `init` method from:

```
init: ->
```

to:

```
init: =>
```

to ensure that the value of `this` has something to refer to when the event handler is defined.